# Print two-sided flash cards for learning on paper

Tags: printing, csv

I have a simple CSV file like this:

```
Question;Answer
Capital of Australia?; Canberra
Capital of Austria?; Vienna
```

I want to print these questions on DIN-A4 paper. On the front the questions and on the backside (second print, I don't have duplex printer) the answers.

The layout on the paper needs to be like this. This way I can cut the paper and get small cards for learning:

```
Q1 Q2 Q3
Q4 Q5 Q6
…
```

The back side:

```
A3 A2 A1
A6 A5 A4
…
```

I guess this has been solved before, but I could not find a software which does this.

Has someone a solution for this?

The software should run on Linux or Windows. Open Source preferred. I would pay up to 10 €, but I won't use a subscription.